# Sobel filter weird output

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection

I am trying to implement a sobel filter to locate horizontal edges in a 160x120 pixel image that is captured from a OV7725 CMOS camera module that outputs RGB565 data.

I've done the RGB565 -> 8-bit grayscale conversion as can be seen in the first picture[image: RGB565 to 8-bit grayscale]

However, when I try to do my sobel operation on the grayscale picture it gets a bit funky and the output is multiplied for some reason. I've been looking at my implementation but can't seem to find out what is wrong...

[image: Filtered grayscale iamge]

Below is my implementation in C and I don't really care about the pixel at the edges.

```
void sobelFilter(int8_t *inputImg, int8_t *outputImg)
{
    uint16_t row;
    uint16_t col;
    uint16_t pos;

    int16_t pixel_x;
    int16_t pixel_y;

    const int8_t sobel_h[3][3] = {
            {-1, 0, 1},
            {-2, 0, 2},
            {-1, 0, 1}
    };

    for (row = 1; row < 120 - 1; row++)
    {
        for (col = 1; col < 160 - 1; col++)
        {
            pos = 120 * row + col;

            pixel_x = inputImg[pos - 121] * sobel_h[0][0];
            pixel_x += inputImg[pos - 119] * sobel_h[0][2];

            pixel_x += inputImg[pos - 1] * sobel_h[1][0];
            pixel_x += inputImg[pos + 1] * sobel_h[1][2];

            pixel_x += inputImg[pos + 119] * sobel_h[2][0];
            pixel_x += inputImg[pos + 121] * sobel_h[2][2];

            outputImg[pos] = sqrt( (pixel_x * pixel_x) );) );
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something funky with my implementation that I've missed or am doing wrong? Like why is it producing 3 copies of the "object" and why is the filtered image not being filtered the whole way down?

Comment: The reason why it was not going through the whole picture was because one line was wrong, it position should be pos = 120 * col + row;

However, no idea why its producing multiple outputs :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using a threshold value for the pixel value that I got from sqrt( (pixel_x * pixel_x) );[image]